# Processing key/value options with many non-predefined keys

Tags: key-value

Say I want to define a command `\defineaspect` that takes a key/value option list to associate values with keys that are not known in advance. For example, to associate certain aspects with a list of persons, a use of that command might look like

```
\defineaspect{forename}{
    .print = {},
    sherlock = Sherlock,
    jim = James
}
\defineaspect{surname}{
    .print = \scshape,
    sherlock = Holmes,
    jim = Moriarty
}
```

`sherlock` and `jim` should then be treated kind of like primary keys in a database table with the various aspects being further columns in that table. Additionally, some actually predefined keys might occur in this list too, like `.print` in the example.

I had a glance at some of the packages for key/value processing, but as far as I can see having a lot of non-predefined keys is not a typical use case for these packages.

Is there a key/value package that provides easy handling of such keys? Or should I better use a custom parser that splits the list at `,` first and then parses each key/value pair separately?

Comment: These look like property lists to me: is every value 'some tokens to store'?

Comment: Can't the parsing be easily done with `l3keys` using `unknown .code:n = { ... }` for the keys that aren't know in advance, and normal handling for the other keys?

Comment: As Joseph said, something like `\NewDocumentCommand \defineaspect { mm } { \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { g_siracusa_#1_aspect_prop } {#2} }` should do what you want.

Comment: @frougon Thanks, this approach also seems to work. I misunderstood the documentation in that the `unknown` key were only meant for a custom error message.

Comment: There is no need to implement a parser splitting at `,` and parsing a `key=value` pair, `\keyval_parse:NNn` and `\ekvparse` (from `expkv`) do exactly that for you so that you can provide two macros which should be called each element of your `key=value` list (one if no value was given for an element, one if a value was given).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit `expl3`'s key-value system and the `prop` data type. To turn a key-value list into an `expl3` property list you can use `\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn`. The function will get each `key = value` pair in `#2` and add to the `prop` list in `#1`. A sample document in this case would be:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \defineaspect { mm }
  {
    \prop_new:c { g__siracusa_#1_aspect_prop }
    \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { g__siracusa_#1_aspect_prop } {#2}
  }
%
\tl_new:N \l__siracusa_tmpa_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \getaspect { mm }
  {
    \prop_get:cnNTF { g__siracusa_#1_aspect_prop } {#2} \l__siracusa_tmpa_tl
      { \tl_use:N \l__siracusa_tmpa_tl }
      { Aspect~#2~does~not~exist~in~#1! }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \fullname { m }
  {
    { \getaspect { forename } { .print } \getaspect { forename } {#1} ~ }
    { \getaspect { surname  } { .print } \getaspect { surname  } {#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\defineaspect{forename}{
    .print = {},
    sherlock = Sherlock,
    jim = James
}
\defineaspect{surname}{
    .print = \scshape,
    sherlock = Holmes,
    jim = Moriarty
}
\begin{document}
Did you miss me? --- \fullname{jim}
\end{document}
```

However this does a one-to-one translation of the input to the data structure. If you need a finer-grained control of that process, say, to differentiate simple keys from key from "special" keys, like `.print`, then you could use `\keyval_parse:NNn`.

`\keyval_parse:NNn` takes two functions and a key-value list as argument. `\keyval_parse:NNn` iterates through the key-value list in `#3` and uses function `#1` or `#2` in each item of the list depending if the item has only a key or a key and a value.

A reimplementation of the `\defineaspect` above would become:

```latex
\prop_new:N \l__siracusa_tmpa_prop
\NewDocumentCommand \defineaspect { mm }
  {
    \prop_clear:N \l__siracusa_tmpa_prop
    \keyval_parse:NNn \__siracusa_aspect:n \__siracusa_aspect:nn {#2}
    \prop_new:c { g__siracusa_#1_aspect_prop }
    \prop_gset_eq:cN { g__siracusa_#1_aspect_prop } \l__siracusa_tmpa_prop
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__siracusa_aspect:n #1
  { \__kernel_msg_error:nnn { kernel } { prop-keyval } {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__siracusa_aspect:nn #1#2
  { \prop_put:Nnn \l__siracusa_tmpa_prop {#1} {#2} }
```

The error message in the definition of `\__siracusa_aspect:n` is there only to mimick the behaviour of `\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn`, but of course you can change that to the appropriate action when only a key is given.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `\keyval_parse:NNn`. I believe the second code sample would appreciate `\prop_gset_eq:cN` and `\prop_put:Nnn`, wouldn't it? ;-)

Comment: @frougon Ouch :| Fixed. Thanks for pointing it out :-)